# TOAD query result is cut in the middle

Tags: toad

I execute a query eith a long textual column name:

```
select column as "a_very_very_long_field_name" 
from table;
```

The result looks like :

```
a_very_very_long_fi  
--------------------

1.

2.

...
```

Is it possible to set the result for unlimited length?